# Add font, format, size button in CKeditor 4

Tags: ckeditor4.x

How to show font, format, size button in tootlbar of ckeditor 4 with existing button ?

[image]

I added CKEditor like below.

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.22.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

I am using below code.

```
var editorConfig = {
      
toolbar: [
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', 'RemoveFormat'] },
    { name: 'styles', items: ['Font', 'FontSize'] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote'] },
    { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Table'] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: ['Format'] }, 
  ],
};


var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor', editorConfig);
```

I am getting output like below.

[image]

Comment: I am using version 5 and I remember that I downloaded the pluginss specifically a long time ago, it should be like this for version 4 as well. If you choose the "full package" at https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder, it comes attached. Have you tried this?